# Custom 404 w/ Referring URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

The redirect .NET uses to send users to my custom 404 page, wipes out the referringURL.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

I understand why.  I'm struggling to figure out the best workaround.

The ultimate goal is to send the user to Error404.aspx with the referringURL as part of the querystring like so...

```
/Error404.aspx?referrer=/referringURLhere.aspx
```

In my current configuration, Error.aspx does receive the aspxerrorpath querystring.  But, I've got nothing in terms of a referringURL on Error404.aspx

The purpose of which, is for reporting inside of Google Analytics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx#customerrors_topic7. You can overload onError.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to also add a section to the `system.webServer` with

```
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I've seen examples of this.  What's the difference between customErrors and `httpErrors errorMode="Custom"`?

Comment: I don't quite remeber as I've taken out the section from one of our existing apps but IF I remember correctly, both sections must exists for this to work on IIS. Few of apps rely heavily on this mechanism and IIS redirects to `ErrorHandler.aspx?404;http://referringUrlHere`.

Comment: The application already had the `httpErrors errorMode="Custom"` in the web.config  Thanks anyway Wiktor!